# Determine features provided by Unix system - autoconf

Tags: sockets, unix, autoconf

I downloaded the autoconf-2.69 from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf and I ran the "autoheader".

After that I copied "AC_CONFIG_HEADER(config.h)" to "configure.in" after the "AC_INIT" line. Ran "autoconf" than again ran "autoheader" and "./configure".

The "configure.h" is generated by it does not give me information about my Unix system.

Am I doing something wrong here?

How can I get information about my Unix system, "Are datalink socket structure are supported?", "Does socket address structure have len field or not?"

Edit: as requested output of `uname -a`
                **Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Comment: You should be using `configure.ac` and not `configure.in`.  You have to test for the features you want, either by invoking an existing test or by writing your own.  You might need to test for the C compiler, whether it supports C11 or C99, whether you've got the headers you need, and then whether the headers contain the information you need.  Generally, you'd do best finding someone else's configuration to work with, removing the stuff you don't need and adding the stuff you do need, rather than trying ab initio.  But that might be perceived as cargo cult programming, too.